# Zeroing out FreeBSD swap space?

Tags: partition, freebsd, swap

I'd like to zero-fill the partitions/slices in my FreeBSD VMs in order to provide for better compression for archival. For those partitions/slices with file systems the process is no problem for me to figure out.

I know I can turn off the swap space use via `swapoff -a`. However, I am uncertain as to whether the swap space has a special structure in FreeBSD and whether I need to reinitialize this structure (like in Linux with `mkswap`) after zero-filling the slice using `dd`.

Can anybody shed light on how I can safely zero-fill the swap space and all partitions such that after shutdown I get the best compression possible?

Comment: You're not using encrypted swap?

Comment: @ott--: how to find that out? `swapinfo`? I am using a range of FreeBSD versions from 6 through 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special structure so there's no harm in doing `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/yourswapdev`. Just be sure you use the right device. :) (Guessing this is a VM otherwise there's no benefit to this.)

Answer (score 1):

I did tried  `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/$someswappartition` to reduce my whole disk image size.

The result is undesirable, the next system boot takes minutes stuck at boot screen.

If your system is configured to use UUID to identify the swap partition (my debian 10/11 does that by default). Zeroing the partition with dd, will effectively destroy the UUID.
Resulting in a unidentifiable swap partition, since it has no UUID. It can't not be swapon/off , and can't be activated on boot resulting in long wait for timeout at  system startup.

After zeroing, use `mkswap /dev/$someparttition  UUID=$ORIGINAL_UUID` to restore the UUID. Then it will work as normal.

Comment: ... as mentioned in my question 

Comment: I got other issues when using full disk dd image, if the restore process has been disrupted for any reason, the SSD  card  will  run into issues preventing a second dd attempt. Even with 7z compress ion the images is still very big compared to file based archiving.  And the speed is also very slow  with compression. So now I only use dd to restore MBR. cfdisk/fsdisk for partition table,  mkfs+tar for partition content.